# Check which cell on a name column is equal to certain text

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I'm new in using Nightwatch and I need help with the following:

I need to check which cell on a name column on a table is equal to a text for example name3

Here's my script for the following but it's not working

```js
var name3 = client.globals.item3.name
for (i = 1; i <=10; i++){
            client.getText("#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child("+ i +") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a > span", function(result) {
            
    client.expect.element("#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child("+ i +") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a > span").text.to.equal(name3);
                
    client.verify.elementPresent('#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child('+ i +') > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a')
                
    client.verify.containsText('#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child('+ i +') > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a', name3)
  i = 11;
  });

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific what do you mean by "it's not working". Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry. It's pointing only to cell 11 when the assertion is performed.

Answer (score 0):

This is all because of asynchronous behavior of nodejs.
Try this

```
function test(i) {
    var name3 = client.globals.item3.name
    client.getText("#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a > span", function (result) {

        client.expect.element("#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a > span").text.to.equal(name3);

        client.verify.elementPresent('#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child(' + i + ') > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a')

        client.verify.containsText('#table > div.ReactTable.noBorder-undefined.noHeader-undefined.compact-undefined.expanded-undefined.no-data-false.subComponentLarge-undefined.undefined.editable-table > div.rt-table > div.rt-tbody > div:nth-child(' + i + ') > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > a', name3)
    });

    while (j <= 10) {
        test(j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works